# How to change multiple div background colors randomly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, random

Maybe what I'm trying to do is impossible, but I'd like to ask before I give up.

I'm editing my blog and would like the background colors of my text posts to change randomly every time the page is visited.

I found this on [teamtreehouse.com](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/random-background-color) from a Google search:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf=8">
    <style type="text/css">
        #posts {
            width: 90%;
            height: 700px;
            margin: auto
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="return ran_col()">
    <div id="posts">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ran_col() { //function name
            var color = '#'; // hexadecimal starting symbol
            var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0']; //Set your colors here
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
            document.getElementById('posts').style.background = color; // Setting the random color on your div element.
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The effect works really well. The problem I'm having with it is that I have multiple #posts divs and it will only generate a random background color for one of the #posts divs. The rest have no background colors.

I would like each #posts div on my site to have a different random color, not the same random color. Is there a way to do that? I'll admit I'm not very good at these sorts of things but once I get an idea in my head I have a hard time letting it go. Any suggestions or tips would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: use class selector then, and use class, id must be unique of each element

Comment: You can have only one element with one id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("posts").style.background = color;
```

instead of

```
 document.getElementById('posts').style.background = color;
```

An Id, must be unique, a class can have multiple items. Maks sure you go change your divs to contain this class instead of the Id you are using.

Example:

```
<div id="posts">
```

should be

```
<div class="posts">
```

Edit#1: 
As per comments below, the css file has has to be changed so that that the IDs become classes. So just change the `#posts` to `.posts`

Edit#2: 
getElementsByClassName will return an array of the elements, you then have to iterate through them to change the background color with something like this:

```
var x = getElementsByClassName("posts");
var i; 
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
   x[i].style.backgroundColor = color; 
}
```

Edit #3: 
This is a final working example of all the above. Try it out. I added a div="page" container that becomes visible at the end of the script so that the divs don't load one after the other.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf=8">
    <style type="text/css">
        .posts {
            width: 90%;
            height: 700px;
            margin: auto
        }
        #page{
            display:none;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
            function ran_col() { //function name
                var color; // hexadecimal starting symbol
                var letters = ['000000','FF0000','00FF00','0000FF','FFFF00','00FFFF','FF00FF','C0C0C0']; //Set your colors here

                var x= document.getElementsByClassName("posts");
                var i;
                for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                {
                    color="#";
                    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
                    x[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
                }
                document.getElementById("page").style.display = "block";
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body onload="ran_col()">
    <div id="page">

        <div class="posts">
            test1
        </div>
        <div class="posts">
            test2
        </div>
        <div class="posts">
        test3
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that none of the #posts divs have background colors. Weird. But thanks, I appreciate this!

Comment: As everyone said, `posts` needs to be a **class** not an **id**. So it will be `.posts` not `#posts`. [The Difference Between ID and Class](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/)

Comment: Yeah I forgot about your css file. Just do as @lkmhr mentionned above in your css and change the `#` symbol for a `.` and it should fix this issue.

Comment: Yes, I did. I changed #posts to .posts and div id to div class but now instead of all the divs having random color background, none of them have backgrounds at all. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: And just for the record I also changed ElementById to ElementsByClassName and 'posts' to "posts" ... sounds like it should work but it's not :/

Comment: I just realised something, the getElementsByClassName will return an array of all the elements, so you can't just change the background color property, you'll have to iterate throught them with a for loop. Here's a quick example of what it would look like: 

`var x = getElementsByClassName("posts");
var i;
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
  x[i].style.backgroundColor = color;
}`

Comment: Ugh I feel like an idiot, I'm very good at css but when it comes to script I haven't a clue. How do I apply that to the script I posted earlier? Thanks @IronWilliamCash I really appreciate all your help and patience!

Comment: I'm looking into solving the issue for you, give me a bit of time.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay, I updated my answer with a working solution. It took me a bit because I screwed up my for loop but it works now. Look for the edit#3 in my above answer

Comment: Thanks @IronWilliamCash it works! Thanks so much for your help, you're awesome. I'm a visual learner and to see it laid out like this I have a better understanding of how it works now. :)

Comment: @justin Great! Glad I could help! It's a basic script, but you can change it up and do what you want with it.